# Using Mockito with Lambda expressions

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda, spring-security, mockito

I have the following class that uses Spring Security configuration and I want to write a unit test on it.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(arc -> arc
                        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer(rsc ->
                        rsc.opaqueToken(
                                (OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.OpaqueTokenConfigurer configurer) ->
                                        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                        )
                );
    }
}
```

I try to write a unit test using Mockito

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SecurityConfigurationTest {

    @Mock private HttpSecurity httpSecurity;
    @Mock private SessionManagementConfigurer<HttpSecurity> sessionManagementConfigurer;

    @InjectMocks
    private SecurityConfiguration securityConfiguration;

    @Test
    void testConfigure() throws Exception {
        when(httpSecurity.authorizeRequests(any(Customizer.class))).thenReturn(httpSecurity);
        when(httpSecurity.sessionManagement()).thenReturn(sessionManagementConfigurer);
        when(sessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .thenReturn(sessionManagementConfigurer);
        when(sessionManagementConfigurer.and()).thenReturn(httpSecurity);
        when(httpSecurity.csrf(any(Customizer.class))).thenReturn(httpSecurity);
        when(httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer(any(Customizer.class))).thenReturn(httpSecurity);

        securityConfiguration.configure(httpSecurity);

        verify(httpSecurity, times(1)).authorizeRequests(any(Customizer.class));
        verify(httpSecurity, times(1)).sessionManagement();
        verify(sessionManagementConfigurer, times(1))
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        verify(sessionManagementConfigurer, times(1)).and();
        verify(httpSecurity, times(1)).csrf(any(Customizer.class));
        verify(httpSecurity, times(1)).oauth2ResourceServer(any(Customizer.class));
    }
}
```

But when I run my unit tests, I see that not all lines of code are covered:

[image]

How to get 100% coverage?

Comment: Why do you even need to do that? Having those lines covered by tests won't prove that your endpoints are secure. Instead write tests that the endpoints can't be accessed by unauthorized people.

Comment: Make sure to read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not about Lambda expressions! Your problem is that you are mocking on

```
when(httpSecurity.authorizeRequests(any(Customizer.class))).thenReturn(httpSecurity);
```

and

```
when(httpSecurity.oauth2ResourceServer(any(Customizer.class))).thenReturn(httpSecurity);
```

These mocks make it so that the Code in your class is not executed because they are mocked. By *removing* these two lines you should see your lines covered (or getting an error in the beginning :) ).